# Calculate duration while condition is True in dated Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I am trying to iteratively count the duration between a number of date-indexed transactions in a Pandas Dataframe.

The DataFrame has one column, `events` indexed by date. If the `event` column == 0, then no open transaction exists for that day.  If the `event` column is not null, however, then I wish to count the number of days until the event next equal to zero and calculate the difference between the index start date and index end date.

My data:

```
import io
import pandas as pd

data = """
date, event,
2015-12-29,      0.000000,
2015-12-30,      0.000000,
2015-12-31,      0.000000,
2016-01-04,      0.000000,
2016-01-05,      0.000000,
2016-01-06,      0.000000,
2016-01-07,      0.000000,
2016-01-08,      0.000000,
2016-01-11,     67.333333,
2016-01-12,     67.333333,
2016-01-13,     67.333333,
2016-01-14,     67.333333,
2016-01-15,     67.333333,
2016-01-18,     67.333333,
2016-01-19,     67.333333,
2016-01-20,     67.333333,
2016-01-21,     67.333333,
2016-01-22,     67.333333,
2016-01-25,    102.000000,
2016-01-26,    102.000000,
2016-01-27,    102.000000,
2016-01-28,    102.000000,
2016-01-29,    102.000000,
2016-02-01,    102.000000,
2016-02-02,    102.000000,
2016-02-03,      0.000000,
2016-02-04,      0.000000,
2016-02-05,      0.000000,
2016-02-15,      0.000000,
2016-02-16,      0.000000,
"""

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), sep=",", index_col='date')
df.head(10)
```

I have tried to replicate this with a for loop and a while loop. My initial thoughts are to loop through each row and whilst `df.iloc[i] != 0` append the start_date and end_date to separate lists, then simply loop each list together calculating the time in days between them.

Unfortunately, I cannot work out how to combine the `while` condition in the `for` loop successfully.

- Expected Outcome *

A list containing the duration, in days of each transaction in the dataframe. For example, the outcome above would be:

```
print(trans_times)

Out: 23
```

I hope the problem is clear, all help gratefully appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do `cumsum` create the sub groupby key

```
df = df.reset_index()
cond = df['event'].eq(0)
df.date=pd.to_datetime(df.date)
df[~cond].groupby(cond.cumsum())['date'].agg(np.ptp) # agg(lambda x : x.max()-x.min())
Out[21]: 
event
8   22 days
Name: date, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```